# Attempted import error: 'behavior' is not exported from 'd3'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, npm

I am trying to make a sankey diagram using d3 and react.js and I am using this example as a reference https://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/9673c96a682fe3948379. I am fairly new to react(2 days) and I am getting this error--

```
./src/components/SankeyComponent.js
```

Attempted import error: 'behavior' is not exported from 'd3' (imported as 'd3').

SankeyComponent.js
This is my code for creating SankeyComponent. As soon as I clear one error other import and export erros are coming up.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactFauxDOM from 'react-faux-dom';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import sankey from 'd3-plugins-sankey';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { NODES } from '../shared/nodes';
import { LINKS } from '../shared/links';

class Sankey extends Component {

     constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            nodes: NODES,
            links: LINKS
        };
    }
    render() {

            // Set units, margin, sizes
            var margin = {top: 1, right: 1, bottom: 6, left: 1},
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),
                format = function(d) { return formatNumber(d) + " TWh"; },
                color = d3.scale.category20();

            // Set the sankey diagram properties

            var sankey = d3.sankey()
                            .nodeWidth(15)
                            .nodePadding(10)
                            .size([width, height]);

            var path = sankey.link();

            //var freqCounter = 1;

            var graph = {
                  nodes: _.cloneDeep(this.state.nodes),
                  links: _.cloneDeep(this.state.links)
                };

            sankey.nodes(graph.nodes)
                  .links(graph.links)
                  .layout(32);

            // Initialize and append the svg canvas to faux-DOM

            var svgNode = ReactFauxDOM.createElement('svg');

            var svg = d3.select(svgNode)
                        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            // Initialize and append the svg canvas to faux-DOM
            var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
                          .data(graph.links)
                          .enter().append("path")
                          .attr("class", "link")
                          .attr("d", path)
                          .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
                          .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });

            link.append("title")
                .text(function(d) { return d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

            // Add nodes

            var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
                          .data(graph.nodes)
                          .enter().append("g")
                              .attr("class", "node")
                              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
                          .call(d3.behavior.drag()
                              .origin(function(d) { return d; })
                              .on("dragstart", function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
                              .on("drag", dragmove));

            node.append("rect")
                  .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
                  .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); })
                  .style("stroke", "none")
            .append("title")
                   .text(function(d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

            node.append("text")
                  .attr("x", -6)
                  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                  .attr("transform", null)
                  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
            .filter(function(d) { return d.x < width / 2; })
                  .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
                  .attr("text-anchor", "start");

            var linkExtent = d3.extent(graph.links, function (d) {return d.value});
            var frequencyScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(linkExtent).range([0.05,1]);
            //var particleSize = d3.scale.linear().domain(linkExtent).range([1,5]);

            // the function for moving the nodes
            function dragmove(d) {
                d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + (d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - d.dy, d3.event.y))) + ")");
                sankey.relayout();
                link.attr("d", path);
            }

            graph.links.forEach(function (link) {
                link.freq = frequencyScale(link.value);
                link.particleSize = 2.5;
                link.particleColor = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1])
                .range([link.source.color, link.target.color]);
             })



            return (
        <svg>
          {svg.node().toReact()}
          </svg>
    );

    }
}

export default Sankey;
```

Comment: Did you paste all the contents of `SankeyComponent.js` here?

Comment: what version of `d3` are you using?

Comment: "d3": "^4.0.0",

Comment: @shkaper I will paste all the contents. Please have a look I have posted my code

Comment: @Sagivb.g I am using version 4.  Do I have to use version 5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like `d3.behavior.drag` was renamed to `d3.drag` in v4. https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#dragging-d3-drag

Since you're using d3 v4, you can either update your code or downgrade to v3

Comment: So i should work with version 4 and change the code to d3.drag

Comment: ./node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/info.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '...app\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib'   Now i get this error

Comment: Is it because I have not installed webpack?

Comment: I don't know but that seems irrelevant to the question. You could try to ask a new one and add some context, i.e. what is your `package.json` what build tools you're using, etc.